# Somar valores de várias linhas sob condição

Tags: sql, postgresql

Boa tarde senhores, tenho uma consulta que me retorna alguns campos preciso da soma deles, só que perante uma condição

```
 select adm.adm_ds_administradora as descricao,
        sum(car.car_vl_cartao) as valor,
        'Cartão TEF'        as cartao,
        cast ('' as varchar) as fun_ds_funcionario,
        cast ('' as varchar) as ntd_vl_acrescimo,
        cast ('' as varchar) as ntd_vl_desconto,
        cast ('' as varchar) as ntd_vl_pago,
        cast ('' as varchar) as ntd_vl_saldo,
        cast ('' as varchar) as agrupamento,
        rank() over(
 order by adm.adm_ds_administradora) as ordenacao,
          adm.adm_fl_tipo,
          *CASE WHEN adm.adm_fl_tipo = 'D' then
            SUM(car.car_vl_cartao)
          END as total,*
          1 as CONSTANTE
 from financeiro.cartao car,
      cadastro.administradora adm
 where car.car_cd_administradora = adm.adm_cd_administradora
       and car.car_cd_caixa in (576785)
       and adm.adm_ds_bandeira_tef is not null
 group by adm.adm_cd_administradora
 order by 3,
          ordenacao,
          1
```

(*CASE WHEN adm.adm_fl_tipo = 'D' then
                SUM(car.car_vl_cartao)
              END as total,*) Não está funcionando!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de um total acumulativo para quando o tipo for igual a 'C' e quando for igual a 'D'.Ir somando os valores onde o tipo for igual a 'C' simplificando.

Comment: Mesmo com o else não está funcionando.

Comment: coloca adm_fl_tipo no group by

Comment: Fiz isso, mudou nada, pois os tipos são iguais mas valores diferem..Pensei em usar laço de repetição talvez.. não sei

Comment: monta o ambiente aqui por favor: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15

Answer (score 3):

A função de agregação `sum()` deve ficar *fora* do `CASE`, veja só:

```
SUM( CASE WHEN adm.adm_fl_tipo = 'D' THEN car.car_vl_cartao ELSE 0 END ) AS total
```

Isso vai fazer com que o valor zero (`0`) seja somado ao resultado total sempre que a condição do `CASE WHEN` não for verdadeira.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO:

```
sum(sum(car.car_vl_cartao) filter(where adm.adm_fl_tipo = 'D')) over(order by adm.adm_ds_administradora) as accum_debito,
sum(sum(car.car_vl_cartao) filter(where adm.adm_fl_tipo = 'C')) over(order by adm.adm_ds_administradora) as accum_credito,
```

Desta forma acima, consegui fazer os acumulativos, obrigado a todos que contribuíram de alguma forma.